# Loading random scene by scene name works in editor but not in standalone app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a manager script that stores a collection of strings in a List that are coming from an array of Object names. These objects are actually my game scenes that I'm dragging into a public array in the unity editor. From there I'm picking one of these strings in GetRandomScene() and then passing the string name through LoadScene() to `SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);`.

This script is attached to a blank scene (first scene in build settings) with the purpose of loading one of the scenes that I've dragged into the Object[] forestScenes array. This works fine in the editor, but it doesn't work when I build as a standalone app. What do I need to modify for this to function correctly?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ForestGameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ForestGameManager fgm = null; // create singleton

    [Header("Network Prefab")]
    public GameObject serverNetworkManagerPrefab;

    [Header("Forest Scenes")]
    public Object[] forestScenes;
    private List<string> forestSceneNames;
    private int randomSceneIndex;
    private string randomSceneName;

    [Header("Forest Animal Management")]
    public int maxAnimalCount = 4;
    public List<ForestAnimal> forestAnimals;

    private void Awake()
    {
        StartCoroutine(InitForestGameManager());
        StartCoroutine(InitServerNetworking());
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        forestAnimals = new List<ForestAnimal>();
        forestSceneNames = new List<string>();

        StartCoroutine(InitSceneNameList());

        StartCoroutine(GetRandomScene());
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Destroy oldest animal gameobject based on maxAnimalCount
        if (forestAnimals.Count >= maxAnimalCount)
        {
            GameObject toDestroy = forestAnimals[0].forestAnimalGO;
            forestAnimals.RemoveAt(0);
            Destroy(toDestroy);
        }
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        // If all forest scenes have been used, re-initialize scene name list and pick the next random scene
        if (forestSceneNames != null)
        {
            if (forestSceneNames.Count == 0)
            {
                StartCoroutine(InitSceneNameList());
                StartCoroutine(GetRandomScene());
            }
        }
        // Start scene change countdown timer
    }

    private IEnumerator InitSceneNameList()
    {
        // Initialize scene name list
        for (int i = 0; i < forestScenes.Length; i++)
        {
            forestSceneNames.Add(forestScenes[i].name);
            // Debug.Log("Scene " + forestSceneNames[i].ToString() + " added to string list.");
        }
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    private IEnumerator InitForestGameManager()
    {
        if (fgm == null)
            fgm = this;
        else if (fgm != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    private IEnumerator InitServerNetworking()
    {
        Instantiate(serverNetworkManagerPrefab);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    private IEnumerator GetRandomScene()
    {
        // Get scene name from random pick
        randomSceneName = forestSceneNames[Random.Range(0, forestSceneNames.Count)];
        // Remove selected scene from list
        forestSceneNames.Remove(randomSceneName);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        // Load selected scene
        StartCoroutine(LoadScene(randomSceneName, 1.0f));

        //Debug.Log("randomSceneName is " + randomSceneName);

        for (int i = 0; i < forestSceneNames.Count; i++)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Scene " + forestSceneNames[i].ToString() + " is still left in the list");
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator LoadScene(string sceneName, float loadDelay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(loadDelay);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the scenes are included in the build settings of the game, otherwise Unity won't compile them into the game files.

Comment: Yes, they are all in the build settings

Comment: Are you getting any errors when playing in the standalone app, when the scenes should be loaded?

Comment: I'm not getting errors when I load the app. This script is attached to a blank scene (first scene in build settings) with the purpose of loading one of the scenes that I've dragged into the Object[] forestScenes array.

Comment: Can you check the `output_log.txt` file, just to ensure everything's working?